# Using left join with many tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my code:

```
SELECT a.accNumber,
    a.Rest,
    dateadd(day, 1, min(a.DATE)),
    min(b.DATE)
FROM t1 a
LEFT JOIN t1 b
    ON a.accNumber = b.accNumber
WHERE a.DATE <> b.DATE
    AND a.DATE < b.DATE
    AND a.Rest <> 0
    AND a.accNumber = b.accNumber
GROUP a.accNumber,
    a.Rest
ORDER BY a.accNumber,
    3
```

What I want to do is to add accName attribute (to select statement) from table t2, so that accountID of table t1 equals accountID of table t2. Left join makes it difficult to do. Please help. Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.accNumber,b.accName,
    a.Rest,
    dateadd(day, 1, min(a.DATE)),
    min(b.DATE)
FROM t1 a
LEFT JOIN t2 b
    ON a.accNumber = b.accNumber
        AND a.DATE <> b.DATE
        AND a.DATE < b.DATE
        AND a.Rest <> 0
GROUP BY a.accNumber,b.accName,
    a.Rest
ORDER BY a.accNumber,
    3
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand. Where is accName attribute form t2?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use two `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.accNumber, a.Rest, dateadd(day,1,MIN(a.Date)), MIN(b.Date), t2.accName
FROM t1 a
LEFT JOIN t1 b ON a.accNumber=b.accNumber 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON a.accId = t2.accId
WHERE a.Date<b.Date 
AND a.Rest<>0 
AND a.accNumber=b.accNumber
GROUP BY a.accNumber, a.Rest
ORDER BY a.accNumber, 3
```

I also fixed few mistakes:

- I added `BY` in `GROUP BY` clause;
- I have removed a redundant condition in `WHERE` clause (`p != q AND p < q` is equivalent to `p < q`)

Comment: Thanks, I've done it. Your help was very important))